# Disable gridview controls using jquery in aspx form

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a form in which there is a CheckBox and a gridview. When I uncheck the CheckBox I want controls in my Gridview to be disabled. here is my gridview aspx:

```
                            <div id="gridVersion" runat="server">
                                <ac:GridViewWithPager ID="gdvwAllowedVersion" runat="server" UseCustomPager="True"
                                    AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="50%">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="centerdata">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdblSelectedVersionList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%#Eval("IsSelected") %>'
                                                    EnableViewState="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdblSelectedVersionList_CheckedChanged" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="2%"></HeaderStyle>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IDEAlliance Version" HeaderStyle-Width="11%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblVersion" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdeAllianceVersion") %>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="11%"></HeaderStyle>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Restrict Import Of" ItemStyle-CssClass="centerdata"
                                            HeaderStyle-Width="2%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="2%">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCheckRestrictImport" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("RestrictedForImport")%>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="2%"></HeaderStyle>
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="2%"></ItemStyle>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Restrict Upgrade To" ItemStyle-CssClass="centerdata"
                                            HeaderStyle-Width="2%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="2%">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCheckRestrictUpgrade" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("RestrictedForUpgrade")%>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="2%"></HeaderStyle>
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="2%"></ItemStyle>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </ac:GridViewWithPager>
                            </div>
```

My CheckBox control is something like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkActivateSettings" runat="server" Text="Activate Restriction Settings.">
                                    </asp:CheckBox>
```

I have already written a Jquery code that hides and shows this grid. But now what I want is to disable control in this grid upon unchecking the CheckBox. So I want to modify this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('#<%=chkActivateSettings.ClientID %>').is(":checked")) {
        //show the hidden div
        $('#<%=gridVersion.ClientID %>').show("fast");
    }
    else {
        //otherwise, hide it
        $('#<%=gridVersion.ClientID %>').hide("fast");
    }
    // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
    $('#<%=chkActivateSettings.ClientID %>').click(function () {

        // If checked
        if ($('#<%=chkActivateSettings.ClientID %>').is(":checked")) {
            //show the hidden div
            $('#<%=gridVersion.ClientID %>').Ena("fast");
        }
        else {
            //otherwise, hide it
            $('#<%=gridVersion.ClientID %>').hide("fast");
        }
    });

});
```

Looking forward to your usual cooperation.

Comment: Is GridViewWithPager custom user control ? Does it have Enabled property like normal asp.net's gridview ?

Comment: Yes it it is a custom control. It inherits from GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Add Enabled="True" to gridview markup:

```
<ac:GridViewWithPager ID="gdvwAllowedVersion" runat="server" Enabled="True" UseCustomPager="True" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="50%">
```

2) Use Jquery's DOM manipulation method `attr(key, value)` to enable/disable gridview:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
    $('#<%=chkActivateSettings.ClientID %>').click(function () {

        // If checked
        if ($('#<%=chkActivateSettings.ClientID %>').is(":checked")) {
            //show the hidden div
            $('#<%=gdvwAllowedVersion.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            //otherwise, hide it
            $('#<%=gdvwAllowedVersion.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: $('#<%=gridVersion.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", true); does not disable the grid.

Comment: 1. Does it hide gridview or ? 2. Does it fire checked change event ?

Comment: yes it did fire (I checked through alert). and nothing happened.